# Virtualization is enabled in BIOS but is not working in Windows 11

Tags: bios, virtualization, windows-11, vt-x, hardware-virtualization

I have an Intel i7-9700K, and everywhere keeps saying that virtualization is not enabled.

I've checked and it is indeed enabled in the BIOS, but it isn't working in Windows 11 Pro 21H2.

The Intel Processor Identification Utility says that Virtualization, Hyper-Threading, and VT-x are unavailable.

First notified of this by Kaspersky stating "Hardware virtualization is not available. Incompatible hardware or software detected."

The additional hypervisor that may be causing issues could be VMware. I installed a trial of it and then went back to VirtualBox, but I had to go to and thoroughly delete the remnants to install Kaspersky, as it was giving me errors on install. 
So *the other hypervisor could be VMware*, but I already tried to thoroughly delete the remnants.

Comment: See what this utility says about your virtualization, scroll down an read how to run it>>>>https://www.grc.com/securable.htm

Comment: How did you determine it’s not working in Windows exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound I kept getting notifications and some VM stuff wouldn’t work

Comment: Do you have Hyper-V installed? If the Intel utility says it’s disabled but you have hardware virtualization enabled (VT-X) then you have software installed giving you a false negative (although it’s still unavailable to whatever software your trying to install).

Comment: @Ramhound both are enabled

Comment: @Bananas - The Intel utility will report that hardware virtualization is disabled if you run it on a system with Hyper-V is enabled, that is expected, since other Hypervisors are unable to use VT-X while Hyper-V is enabled. Care you to be specific about the errors you received?

Comment: @Moab it says that 64-bit processing is available (of course), Hardware D.E.P is available, but Hardware Virtualization is not.

Comment: @Ramhound Kaspersky has a notification that "Hardware virtualization is not available. Incompatible hardware or software detected."

Comment: @Bananas - So edit your question to mention that but that’s also expected since you have Hyper-V enabled. I am confused, what does Hardware D.E.P, have to do with hardware virtualization (VT-X)? Hardware D.E.P has to do with process isolation and process memory protection (I.e not allowing non-elevated processes access another process’s memory space)

Comment: Do you have, Device Guard (Core Isolation) or VBS, enabled? Only one Hypervisor (Hyper-V) can use hardware virtualization, all that means is it’s unavailable to Kaspersky. Editing you question to include vital information is key to getting a complete answer

Comment: @Ramhound Core isolation is on, but what's VBS?

Comment: @Bananas - It stands for Virtualization-based security and uses hardware virtualization to keep the operating system (memory space) secure. You might want to do research if it's required to anything you currently are running.  Why don't you just disable hardware virtualization within Kaspersky?

Comment: @Ramhound Core isolation and "Memory integrity" are enabled in Windows Defender.

Comment: @Bananas - If you want Kaspersky's hardware virtualization feature to be turned on you will have to disable both of those Windows security features

Comment: @Bananas click the box to get extra information for virtualization

Answer (score 0):

> First notified of this by Kaspersky stating, "Hardware virtualization is not available. Incompatible hardware or software detected."

Based on your information, Core isolation (Device Guard) and Virtualization-based Security (VBS) are both enabled. VBS specifically uses hardware virtualization.  Only one hypervisor is allowed to use VT-x at a time; to allow  Kaspersky to use it, you must disable both Core Isolation and Virtualization-based Security (VBS).

You should also disable `Hyper-V`, `Windows Hypervisor Platform`, & `Virtual Machine Platform`

Source: [About protection through hardware virtualization in Kaspersky applications](https://support.kaspersky.co.uk/common/safemoney/13713#block1)

> The additional hypervisor that may be causing issues could be VMware. I installed a trial of it and then went back to VirtualBox, but I had to go to and thoroughly delete the remnants to install Kaspersky, as it was giving me errors on install.

Uninstall VMWare and VirtualBox as they are incompatible with the hardware virtualization feature of Kaspersky.

Comment: Turned VBS off in Windows Defender and virtualization still does not work.

Comment: You have disabled everything I have suggested and rebooted? If you still cannot enable hardware virtualization within Kaspersky, then you have an unspecified hypervisor still installed and enabled, [edit] your question with enough information to identify that hypervisor and I will update my answer.

Comment: I have now disabled Hyper-V, Windows Hypervisor, and VM Platform and the Intel Processor Identification Utility now shows that virtualization and VT-x are available, but not hyper-threading. VirtualBox is still installed.